# What is good software for building 2D parallax videos?

Tags: video-editor, animation-rendering

I am wanting opinions for the best software to put together 2D parallax video content, using flat images, etc.

What do you suggest?

P.S. Could not create the tags parallax or 2d (rep). Sorry for the lack of tagging.

Comment: Obviously After Effects, is an option here, but I'm looking for others.

Comment: After Effects has competitors - try a search (I can't think of any off the top of my head). AE would be my recommendation, any day of the week.

Comment: @nchpmn Thanks for the comment. I'm going to do some more intense searching. The very little response I've got to this question tells me that it's information which needs digging up. What I find, I'll post as an answer on here for others.